# print an array within an array if an array value equals x Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to practice my skills a bit by writing a simple terminal program that finds a hiking spot in Vancouver. (While this may not be the best way to write the program in the end, I'm trying to test my array skills with this program.)

What I've done is put 5 hiking spots in a 2 dimensional array. Each array includes the name, location, difficulty, and length of the hike. I want the user to enter their preferences and then print out the matching hikes.

E.g. If the user enters 6km, I want to print out the hike names from the arrays that are <= 6km.

So I want to print the following code but only when [0] <= 6  in "#{hikes[i][0]}"

```
    hikes.each_index{|i| puts "#{hikes[i][0]} " }
```

Thanks for the help!

Here's my code so far:

```
    #Hiking Array: [Hike Name, Location, Difficulty, Length(km)] 

    hikes = 
    [["Admiralty Point", "Tri Cities", "Easy", 5],
    ["Habrich Ridge Trail", "Howe Sound", "Intermediate", 7],
    ["Aldergrove Regional Park", "Surrey",  "Easy", 5],
    ["Alice Lake", "Howe Sound", "Easy", 6],
    ["Ancient Cedars Trail", "Whistler", "Intermediate", 5]]


    puts "It's the weekend! Where should we go hiking?\n\n"
    puts "Here is the list of available hikes."
    puts "___________________________"

    hikes.each_index{|i| puts "#{hikes[i][0]} " }

    puts "\n"
    puts "How many kilometers do we want to hike?"
    kilometers = $stdin.gets.chomp

    puts "\n"
    puts "How hard do we want the hike to be, Easy or Intermediate?"
    difficulty = $stdin.gets.chomp

    puts "\n"
    puts "What area of town do we want to hike in:"
    puts "Tri Cities"
    puts "Howe Sound"
    puts "Surrey"
    puts "Whistler"
    area_of_town = $stdin.gets.chomp

    puts "\n"
    puts "Ok searching for awesome views that are #{kilometers}km, of #{difficulty} difficulty, and are in #{area_of_town}."

    hikes.each_index{|i| puts "#{hikes[i][2]}"}
```

Comment: It would be a better question, if you narrow the code down, like removing everything not relavent to the core problem. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't iterate by index unless you have to. `hikes.each{|hike| puts "#{hike[0]} " }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
hikes.select {|arr| arr[3] <= 5}.each{|arr| puts arr[0]}
```

But I would suggest using a hash so you can use name the attribute you're looking for.

```
hikes = [{'location'=>'Admirality', 'difficulty'=>5}, {'location'=>'Admirality', 'difficulty'=>10}, {'location'=>'Admirality', 'difficulty'=>15}]

hikes.select {|hsh| hsh["difficulty"] <= 10}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It does look like hashes are an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "and" operator `&&` to print names from nested arrays if they match all 3 conditions, like:

```
hikes.each do |h|
    puts h[0] if ( h[3] <= kilometers &&
                    h[2].downcase == difficulty.downcase && 
                    h[1].downcase == area_of_town.downcase )
end
```

- I converted all strings to `downcase` before matching, just in case user input doesn't match case with array string (e.g `"Easy"` vs `"easy"`)
- If you want to print all details of matching arrays, change `puts h[0]` to `puts h.join(', ')`.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing that as follows (after simplifying by eliminating some hike attributes):

```
hikes = 
  [["Admiralty Point", 5],
  ["Habrich Ridge Trail", 7],
  ["Aldergrove Regional Park", 5],
  ["Alice Lake", "Howe Sound", 6],
  ["Ancient Cedars Trail", 5]]

HIKES_BY_DISTANCE =
  hikes.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) {|a,h| h[a.last] << a}
  #=> {5=>[["Admiralty Point", 5],
  #        ["Aldergrove Regional Park", 5],
  #        ["Ancient Cedars Trail", 5]],
  #    7=>[["Habrich Ridge Trail", 7]],
  #    6=>[["Alice Lake", "Howe Sound", 6]]} 

def select_hikes(length_range)
  HIKES_BY_DISTANCE.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),a|
    a.concat(v) if length_range.cover?(k)
  end
end
```

```
select_hikes(4..5)
  #=> [["Admiralty Point", 5],
  #    ["Aldergrove Regional Park", 5],
  #    ["Ancient Cedars Trail", 5]] 
select_hikes(2..6)
  #=> [["Admiralty Point", 5],
  #    ["Aldergrove Regional Park", 5],
  #    ["Ancient Cedars Trail", 5],
  #    ["Alice Lake", "Howe Sound", 6]] 
select_hikes(4..7)
  #=> [["Admiralty Point", 5],
  #    ["Aldergrove Regional Park", 5],
  #    ["Ancient Cedars Trail", 5],
  #    ["Habrich Ridge Trail", 7],
  #    ["Alice Lake", "Howe Sound", 6]] 
select_hikes(6..9)
  #=> [["Habrich Ridge Trail", 7],
  #    ["Alice Lake", "Howe Sound", 6]] 
select_hikes(7..7)
  #=> [["Habrich Ridge Trail", 7]] 
select_hikes(1..2)
  #=> [] 
select_hikes(8..9)
  #=> []
```

Comment: Yeah it looks like hashes might be a better way to do this. This is helpful, thanks.